# Mistakenly Deleted suphp.conf file

Tags: php, server, centos, suphp

I used apache 2.2.4 webserver in my server and it uses su_php but I mistakenly deleted http-suphp.conf file and my website doesn't run. I searched for any solution but I got nothing.
the path of su_php in my httpd.conf file is :

```
conf/extra/httpd-suphp.conf
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect us to do about it? You can find an example of a config [here](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=suphp.conf-example).

Comment: Reinstall the according distro package?

Answer (score 0):

as jon stirling has mentioned you can take the file and save it in the correct folder and restart your web server...

that file has some parameters you can patiently read and edit/tweak to your liking...

and no, you don't have to reinstall..(again i am assuming its your linux machine)

Comment: thanks. i add the example codes to the appropriate file but apache sends error i think it's because of version of apache